# Creating Category list in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

Hello I am trying to create a Categories list in my Sidebar. However, all the information I am finding regarding the category list doesn't allow me to style the list. Ideally I would like to only list the top 5 most popular but right now I just want to figure out how to properly access the data.

when I use this code

```
           <?php
               $terms = get_terms('category'); /*Name Of category*/
               foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
               echo $term->name.'<br/>  '.$term->count.'<br/>';
                }
                ?>
```

every thing works ok but I am unable to add any css or html

```
     <div class="category" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="300">
          <h2>Popular Categories</h2>

          <?php
           $terms = get_terms('category'); /*Name Of category*/
           foreach ( $terms as $term )
            ?>
       
          <ul class="category-list">
            <li class="list-items" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="400">
              <a href="#"><?php echo $term->name. ;?> </a> <span>(<?php echo $term->count. ;?> ) 
             </span>
            </li>
          </ul>
      <?php endforeach; wp_reset_query();?>
        </div>
```

any help would be great!

Comment: You declare `foreach` loop in the wrong way mention`:` where you start the `foreach` you can check on [PHP forach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

Answer (score 1):

You are using two different kind of [`foreach`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php). The first one, you use curly brackets syntax:

```
foreach($variables as $each){
    //codes
}
```

It works fine as it is as intended format. The second one failed due to wrong syntax usage. To use `foreach() .. endforeach;`, you need to add *colon sign* (`:`) right after foreach declaration:

```
foreach():
    //codes
endforeach;
```

Without this one colon sign character, your code will be treated like the first version, but without curly brackets.

Therefore, your code should look like this:

```
<?php
$terms = get_terms('category'); /*Name Of category*/
foreach ( $terms as $term ):
?>
   
<ul class="category-list">
  <li class="list-items" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="400">
    <a href="#"><?php echo $term->name. ;?> </a> <span>(<?php echo $term->count. ;?> )</span>
  </li>
</ul>
<?php
endforeach;
wp_reset_query();
?>
```